# output sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm a noob at php so I need a bit of help. I have a table with a list of hotels, the columns are

> name | address | city | stars | price

so far I've made a dynamic drop-down menu where the user selects a city from the table, this is shown in the code below:

```
<?php

connection stuff blah blah

?>

<?php   
$sql = "SELECT city FROM hotels";
$result_db = $db->query($sql);
if (!$result_db) {
    echo $db->error . ' Error perform query!';
} else {
    echo '<select name="value">';
    echo '<option value="">-Select from below-</option>';
    while ($row = $result_db->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<option city="' . $row->city . '">';
        echo $row->city;
        echo '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';


}

?>
```

How would I now create a table where all the details of hotels in the selected city are outputted? I'm assuming I need another sql query, arrays (perhaps?) which then I echo into a table? :S But I have no idea how to.....

Comment: No. You just need to select the hotels at the same time that you're selecting the city.

Comment: You need to set up your data structure correctly first, for example by adding a `cities` table and linking your hotels to entries in there. With what you have now, your city dropdown can have multiple entries of the same city, leading to data redundancy. You could of course use `SELECT DISTINCT` but that just hides the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery to add event to your dropdown second in your table you should have an ID field..

You're table should be
         Id | name | address | city | stars | price

next you need to create a query that will fetch the id and name fields and put it on a dropdown.
next you need to use jquery to add event to dropdown.

```
 $(function() {
      $("#hotel").change(function() {

      });
 })
```